# Idioms- can the one in concern have a literal meaning?

Tags: idioms

**I took a fall** and injured myself.
Can the phrase ever be used to describe literal falls?

I know it has a meaning in boxing, but what I'm asking is if you fell and..let's say you broke your knee, could you later say "I took a fall and broke my knee", instead of "I fell and broke my knee"?

Comment: Can you check, did you mean "and" instead of "an".  What do you suppose the figurative meaning to be?  I know "take a fall" has a meaning in boxing, is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I know, i looked it up. But, what i'm asking is, if you fell on and..let's say you broke your knee, could you later say "I took a fall and broke my knee", instead of "i fell and broke my knee"? @JamesK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes used literally, for example:

> Kesha took a fall on stage at a show ([source](http://now100fm.com/kesha-took-fall-stage-show-video/))
>
> When I took a fall and broke my arm, Michelle called me at home to see how I was recovering.

I believe this use is more common in America.

But you should be aware that the idioms suggest doing something on purpose, either losing a boxing match on purpose, or being the scapegoat (to protect someone else)

Comment: Right. I suppose that could be discerned from the context, whether we're talking about someone doing something to save someone, or that boxing match thing. 
Thank you for the help. :)